# To print the list of user_id from the string list

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have  a problem, i have a query that just simply displays the user id in set,for retreieving the user id i am calling the function and it gives me the below list as string

```
SELECT u.user_id
FROM user u
WHERE u.user_id
IN (
'2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 13, 23, 43, 53, 63, 73'
)
```

but when i execute this query it displays only the first user_id ie: 2 and all the user id are present in the database
So any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: @murtuza007: tick mark the answer which suits you best and vote up the remaininng good answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
SELECT u.user_id FROM user u WHERE u.user_id IN ( '2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 13, 23, 43, 53, 63, 73' )
```

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,217174

Im almost surprised you had any match.. each of the numbers in your in list, need to be individual strings, eg '1','2','3' etc.

Comment: Hi could i split the string into idividual list

Comment: Of course you can, wherever you find that data from, you need to split it up so its the right format for the query, at the moment. Its not. In which case what code are you using behind the scenes to call the query, what language is it? how are you actually calling the query?

Comment: i am using mysql stored procedure

Comment: where is that string of user IDs generated?

Comment: '2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 13, 23, 43, 53, 63, 73'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9685/discussion-between-murtuza007-and-bugfinder)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes:

```
IN ( 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 13, 23, 43, 53, 63, 73 )
```

Comment: this is not hard coded this value comes from a function that returns  as text

Comment: Read explode and implode functions of php and see if it can help

Answer (score 1):

Remove single quotes like this and try code again-

```
SELECT u.user_id FROM user u WHERE u.user_id IN ( 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 13, 23, 43, 53, 63, 73);
```